# Correct way represent "everywhere"

Tags: sentence

I want to express that the homeless are everywhere. Here is my 
example:

`They are everywhere, in the park, library, and restaurants.`

1. Is there any mistake in the sentence?
2. When should I add `,` between different locations?

Thank you

Comment: The grammar is imperfect. You need the plural form of the nouns. I'd suggest: *They are everywhere; in parks, libraries and even in restaurants*.

Comment: The homeless are in restaurants? Maybe begging or sleeping outside these places but *inside*? Or do you mean management hire the homeless to work there? maybe change the preposition "in" with "outside restaurants"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***EVERYWHERE***

adverb

: in or to every place or part.

As ***EVERYWHERE*** includes such places as 'in the park, library, and restaurants',

you should use a ***colon*** like this:

"They are everywhere: in the park, library, and restaurants."

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***colon***

: a punctuation mark

used chiefly to direct attention to matter

(such as a list, explanation, quotation, or amplification)

that follows.

Comment: Thank you for the quick prompt. If I would like to add `etc` in the end of the sentence, what should it look like?

Comment: It is: ''They are everywhere: in the park, library, and restaurants, etc.''.

Comment: Why is "park" and "library" in the singular? I mean, the OP's sentence uses the singular but do you consider it appropriate?

Comment: Why not? I think it's OK to say both 'parks, libraries, restaurants' and 'park, library, restaurant'. The original sentence is appropriate as well. The context is limited, so we don't know what number of places the author means.